# C++: Return-by-value, vs return-by-reference of persistent object?

Tags: c++, optimization, return, return-by-reference, return-by-value

Which is better for program speed after compiler-optimization: return-by-value, or return-by-reference to a persistent object?

```
/// Generate a 'foo' value directly as a return type.
template< typename T >
inline T gen_foo();

/// Get a 'foo' reference of a persistent object.
template< typename T >
inline T const& get_foo();
```

`T` will be primitives, pointers, member-pointers, or user-defined small, P.O,D.-like data.

To the best of my knowledge it is pass-by-value, but there is a possible case for pass-by-reference:

- pass-by-value:

  - returning one `T` is a smaller object and fast to copy into a caller's variable.
  - optimizer can use (N)RVO and copy-elision to remove return copies.
  - optimizer can inline the generating code or the generated value into the caller's code.
  - program will not need to access RAM, cached or not.
- pass-by-reference:

  - optimizer might evaluate the persistent value fully, and replace its use with a literal equivalent.  Whether or not this occurs affects the rest of the analysis.
  - if the persistent value is fully-evaluated and substituted as a literal:

    - no value to return.
    - optimizer can inline the literal easily.
    - program won't need to access RAM, cached or not.
  - if the persistent value can't be fully evaluated and substituted:

    - returning one reference is a small object and fast into copy to a caller's variable.
    - optimizer can use (N)RVO and copy-elision to avoid return copies.
    - optimizer can't inline the generating code or the generated value into the caller's code.
    - program would need to access RAM, although this likely would be in L1/L2/etc. cache.

**Background:**

I'm being forced to consider this because on some platforms, some floating-point exceptions get triggered if I return-by-value, but are not if I fill-by-parameter-reference.  ( This is a given; this question is not to debate this point. )  So, the API I wanted, and the API I'm forced to consider using are:

```
/// Generate a 'foo' value directly as a return type.
template< typename T >
inline T gen_foo();

/// Fill in a 'foo' passed in by reference.
template< typename T >
inline void fill_foo( T& r_foo );
```

Since, I abhor the 'fill' API, ( because it separates definition from initialization, prevents creating temporaries, etc., ) I can transform that into a return-by-reference version instead, something like:

```
/// Forward-declare 'Initialized_Foo'.
template< typename T > struct Initialized_Foo;

/// Get a 'foo' reference; this returns a persistent reference to a static object.
template< typename T >
inline T const& get_foo()
{
    #if 0
    // BAD: This calls 'fill_foo' *every* time, and breaks const-correctness.
    thread_local static const T foo;
    fill_foo( const_cast< T& >( foo ) );
    return foo;
    #else
    // GOOD: This calls 'fill_foo' only *once*, and honours const-correctness.
    thread_local static const Initialized_Foo< T > initialized_foo;
    return initialized_foo.data;
    #endif
}

/// A 'foo' initializer to call 'fill_foo' at construction time.
template< typename T >
struct Initialized_Foo
{
    T data;
    Initialized_Foo()
    {
        fill_foo( data );
    }
};
```

Comment: Pass by value, with move semantics enabled, because passing by persistent reference is not safe by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: (btw, getting a floating point error on the return by value is very very weird, and signals that you need to follow the rule of 5 rather than using the default copy/move assignments)

Comment: @MadScienceDreams `T` are primitive types, or tiny structs, such as `Complex<T>`, or `Array<4>`; they tend not to have move-semantics that are different from copy-semantics.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams As long as the lifetime of the object can be guaranteed to outlast that of the references, it is completely safe.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams The default constructor, destructor, copy-constructor, move-constructor, copy-assignment-operator, and move-assignment-operator for primitive and POD `T` are surely safe to use; all composition relies upon it.

Comment: In general, they are safe, but you must be doing something wrong or more fancy, else you would not be getting a floating point exception. Also, making the guarantee that the lifetime of the objects is longer than the reference is a *very hard* problem. The way that you are doing it is not thread safe, and two calls in a row will pass the same reference without guaranteeing a copy of the data. You could do reference counting or pass out a smart ptr to combat this, but all this is treating the symptom rather than the cause (the floating point exception).

Comment: @MadScienceDreams  Lifetime guarantees are part of all APIs: `char const* std::string::c_str()` has a lifetime guarantee; `std::vector<T>::iterator std::vector<T>::begin()` has a lifetime guarantee.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Two calls in a row are fine; there will be two references to the same object.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I updated my example to use C++11 `thread_local` storage.